# Showing which drives are mapped to which users and which groups

Tags: powershell, active-directory

For documentation purposes, I'm trying to create a .csv list of which network shares in my AD domain are accessible by:

1. Every individual user
2. Every group

For instance, for each user x in my domain, I'd like to know which drives x can access. Likewise for each group y, I'd like to know which network drives y can access.

Is there any way to do this directly in Powershell without having to use external tools?

Comment: ACL's are defined at share side. I don't see a way to start from user's end.

I would thus :

1. Parse all servers
2. Identify shares present
3. List defined ACL's ( share and NTFS), both user and group defined
4. Check for a match in your AD

Comment: Note that drive *mappings* (i.e the driver letters assigned to specific smb shares) are client-side details. You can document the permissions of smb *shares* centrally, but you can’t really assume drive X: for one user points to the same as share as drive X: for another user (or even the for the same user on a different workstation).